# Is SemanticOverflow part of Stackoverflow?

Tags: support

I recently accidentialy visited SemanticOverflow.com.

Is this somehow associated with SO? Or what is the relationship there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a SE 1.0 site. It has the following header:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

Comment: So I can't link my other StackExchange accounts to that one?

Comment: @Roflcoptr - no.